# Read instance in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have created a type similar to `Maybe`

`data Defined a = Is a | Undefined`

I made the `Show` instnance

```
instance Show a => Show (Defined a) where
    show (Is a) = show a
    show Undefined = "?"
```

So, I try to implement the instance `Read`

```
instance Read a => Read (Defined a) where
    readsPrec _ s = case (take 1 s) of
                    "?" -> [(Undefined,tail s)]
                    otherwise -> map (\(a,b) -> (Is a,b)) $ readsPrec 0 s
```

That's work, but I can't understand why. Why there is no infinite loop here:

```
otherwise -> map (\(a,b) -> (Is a,b)) $ readsPrec 0 s
```

`readsPrec 0 s` try to read the same string such as in input, isn't it? So it have to go to `otherwise` block yet and form an infinite loop. But the code is really works.

Comment: Note that such `Show` and `Read` instances are shunned in Haskell: `show` should produce valid Haskell code, so `"?"` won't do as a result. If what you're trying to do is just pretty printing, e.g. for ghci, then you should stay with the `Maybe` container and just [use a suitable pretty-printing function](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-interactive-print).

Comment: It's maybe not a good idea for me to use the standard `Maybe` container because I made the `Eq` instance of `Defined` type with differing behaviour

Comment: An `Eq` instance with differing behaviour? I wager that's an even worse idea (but if you properly hide the `Undefined` constructor, it might be ok). At any rate, you shouldn't let the `show (Is a)` print out _only_ the `a` value, without ever mentioning it was wrapped in a `Defined`.

Comment: `(Nothing == Nothing)` is `True` in the implementation of `Eq` for `Maybe` that's not I want for `Defined` type, so I have to create my own type or overload `Eq` for `Maybe` that's even worse.

Comment: Well, but you should not want `Undefined == Undefined` to be false! At least not unless `Undefined` is really some kind of exceptional value that wouldn't ever appear in applications. (Yes, I know that analogously, for floating-point numbers IEEE754 specifies `NaN == NaN` to be false, but that's truely a horrible hack that has caused lots of problems of its own.)

Comment: The right way to deal with equality is to make your type an instance of `Applicative` (just like `Maybe`), and then use `definedEqual :: Eq e => Defined e -> Defined e -> Defined Bool`, defined as `definedEqual a b = (==) <$> a <*> b`.

Comment: Some food for thought: is `read "?" :: Defined (Defined Bool)` equal to `Is Undefined` or `Undefined`? How would you get the other one out of `read`? Can you distinguish between them with your definition of `show`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `readsPrec 0 s` try to read the same string such as in input, isn't it?

Yes it is, but it's not the same `readsPrec`! Let me add a few type annotations:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

instance Read a => Read (Defined a) where
  readsPrec _ = readsDefined

readsDefined :: forall a . Read a => String -> ReadS (Defined a)
readsDefined s = case (take 1 s) of
                    "?" -> [(Undefined,tail s)]
                    otherwise -> map (\(a,b) -> (Is a,b)) $ readsContent s
 where readsContent :: String -> ReadS a
       readsContent = readsPrec 0
```

Note that I can not replace `readsContent` with `readsDefined` here, they're two different functions with incompatible type signature. That's the same situation as in your code, only, there `readsDefined` and `readsContent` are both (different) instantiations of the `readsPrec` method, i.e. they share the same *name* but still have different implementations.